# Preview.app on macOS 11 Big Sur doesn't open files stored on iCloud

Tags: macos, icloud, preview, big-sur

- Preview works fine on files that are stored locally, that is, not in an iCloud folder
- I can open files in an iCloud folder with any other app (e.g. images with GIMP or by pressing spacebar in Finder)

However, I cannot open a file stored on iCloud in Preview (from Finder). I am using Big Sur, has anybody the same problem?

Comment: Are the files downloaded?

Comment: No, same happens also with a screenshot.

Comment: I can't reproduce the problem here. Did you try a reboot already?

Comment: Ok, resolved, thanks for the answers! Logging out from iCloud, restarting and logging in again did the trick.